# Conditional Formatting if Cells in Column Contain Exact Match, Partial or None of Values in Cell

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm stumped on trying to apply conditional formatting to a column based on a cell at the top of the column when the highlighting is dependent on exact match or inverse of match, partial match, or no match. [See example Google Sheet here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WOqRzcMigzqeCpmUVTdkFXP0q7VEbw-tl0-3hmuPfCo/edit?usp=sharing)

Here's the criteria...

**1. Exact matches can be exact or also the inverse of what's in A1.**
For an exact match, the cells in the column that match A1 would be colored green. But, an exact match could be **X,Y**, or the inverse **Y,X**. The point is that an exact match has to have those 2 values, the order doesn't matter.

**2. For partial matches, they need to be colored orange.** A partial match should have one of the values from A1 in the cell. For example, if A1 has **B,D**, then any value can precede or follow a match of one of the values. (B,*) or (*,B) or (D,*) or (*,D) or just B by itself or just D by itself.

**3. Any cells with none of the values from A1 in them are highlighted red.**
So, any cell that does not contain any of the values from A1 should be red.

See spreadsheet link above for further explanation and examples.

Comment: Regex doesn't sound like the right tool for this. Do you have any other choices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have an option with conditional formatting. I don't know if I fully understood your requirements about orange and red, but here you have an option you may be able to adapt

If all the options are a match, it will return green. It's done by splitting and comparing each cell with the value in A1. By counting the Filtered data with REGEXMATCH, and comparing to the amount of items in both cells you'll be able to know if every option is a match

To orange you'll have something similar but without the last step

And for red you use NOT in combination with REGEXMATCH

```
Green: =LET(v,SPLIT($A$1,",",1,1),a,SPLIT(A3,",",1,1),(COUNTA(IFNA(FILTER(a,REGEXMATCH(a,JOIN("|",v)))))=COUNTA(v))*(COUNTA(v)=COUNTA(a)))

Orange: =LET(v,SPLIT($A$1,",",1,1),a,SPLIT(A3,",",1,1),COUNTA(IFNA(FILTER(a,REGEXMATCH(a,JOIN("|",v))))))

Red: =LET(v,SPLIT($A$1,",",1,1),a,SPLIT(TO_TEXT(A3),",",1,1),COUNTA(IFNA(FILTER(a,NOT(REGEXMATCH(a,JOIN("|",v))))))=COUNTA(a))
```

[image]

Comment: by golly, it works! Thanks, Martín! At first, it wasn't working. Then I realized that the order of formula in the Conditional Formatting box needed to be ordered correctly, with green formula at the top, then orange, then red. Once I ordered them that way, it worked. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm glad it was useful! Yes, I thought about clarifying about the order but finally forgot; fortunatelly you found out! Good luck!!

Answer (score 1):

### Alternate Solution:

You may try using `Apps Script` to format a column based on a reference cell. Please see the script below based from your sheets provided.

1. Cell reference is on cell `A1`
2. The script is applied on the values in `Column B2:B`

### Script:

You can use this sample script as a baseline to your problem.

```
function applyConditionalFormatting() {
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet(); //get the active spreadsheeet
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange("B2:B" + lastRow); //declaring the column in which the script will be applied to along with last row with values
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();

  var orangeBackground = '#FFA500';
  var greenBackground = '#00FF00';
  var redBackground = '#ff0000';


  var criteria = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue().toString().split(",");   //getting the value of reference cell

  for (var row = 1; row <= numRows; row++) {
    var cell = range.getCell(row, 1);
    var value = cell.getValue().toString(); // iterating on every value on the range provided

    var hasCriteria = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < criteria.length; i++) {
      var currentCriteria = criteria[i].trim();
      hasCriteria[i] = value.indexOf(currentCriteria) >= 0; //checking if each of the cell value has either "B" or "D"
    }
    var allCriteriaMatched = hasCriteria.every(function (c) {
      return c; //checking if each of the cell value has either "B,D" or "D,B"
    });

    if (allCriteriaMatched) {
      cell.setBackground(greenBackground); //setting the color to green for full match
    } else if (hasCriteria.some(function (c) {
      return c;
    })) {
      cell.setBackground(orangeBackground); // setting the color to orange forp partial match
    } else {
      cell.setBackground(redBackground); //setting the color to red if neither
    }
  }
}
```

### Output:

[image]

Note: I just added a button in the sheet and attached the script above for demo purposes

### References:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app

Comment: Please feel free to ask anything related to the answer posted above.

Comment: I didn't end up using this solution, but wow, what a great way to use GAS. I'll be saving this for future reference. Thanks, George. Brilliant.

Comment: Thank you, @user14915635. I'm glad it helped you in a different way. You can indeed save this for future use.